# What's the solution of the functional equation $ f \big( g ( x ) + y \big) = g \big( f ( x ) + x \big) $?

Tags: functional-equations

I need help with this:

> Find functions $ f , g : \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z $, knowing that $ g $ is injective and such that:
> $$ f \big( g ( x ) + y \big) = g \big( f ( x ) + x \big) \text{, for all } x, y \in \mathbb Z \text . $$

Comment: Did you maybe mean $g(f(x)+y)$, or something to that effect? Otherwise set $x=0$ to get $f(g(0)+y)=g(f(0))$, so that $f$ is constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be an error on the question. As the second member doesn't depend on $y$ then $f$ must be a constant $c$.

$f(g(0) + y) = g(f(0)) = c, \mbox{ for all } y \in \mathbb{Z}$

Then the first member of the equation is a constant, $f(g(x) + y)=c$, so $g$ must also be constant, $c = g(c + x) \mbox{ for all } x \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Maybe you mean $f(g(x)+y) = g(f(y)+x), \mbox{ for all } x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$ ?